# NOMADS grib file naming

Tags: grib, noaa, grib-2

I am looking to run

https://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/examples/usingpython.shtml#example_2

example on wave model data. 
It refers to downloading grib files from

https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/wave/prod/

When I browse into a current date subfolder, what is the naming convention?

I see

```
multi_1.ak_10m.t00z.f000.grib2
```

I assume it must be something like

`multi_1.<LOCATION>_??m.t??z.f<FORECAST_IN_HOURS>.grib2`

LOCATION I see ak - Alaska? , ep - East Pacific? , glo - Global?

What are the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your example:

`<LOCATION>_??m` : the resolution of the model in (arc)minutes

`.t??z` : the time of the model run at which it was started

`.f???` : the number of hours after the model was started

The locations with corresponding notation can be found [here](https://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/implementations.php)

Comment: THanks! When I get data from the Nomads server that has a time tag `11-Oct-2019 03:33`, when was it created? Is this UTC / PST time? https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/wave/prod/multi_1.20191011/

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. Looking at the time stamps I'm inclined to believe it would be UTC but I cannot tell you for certain. Sorry!